# ASP.NET Core Razor runtime compilation and internal classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

In my ASP.NET Core 7 web app, I use Razor [runtime compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation).

`MyApp.csproj`

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="7.0.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

`Program.cs`

```cs
#if DEBUG
if (environment.IsDevelopment())
  builder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
#endif
```

But I get this on start:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:  
error CS0122: 'Foo' is inaccessible due to its protection level  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument, String generatedCode)  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String relativePath)  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(String normalizedPath)  
   ...
```

That is because the `Foo` class is marked as `internal`. I don't remember having this problem in earlier versions.

I added this without success:

```cs
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation")]
```

Can this be done? (Without changing `internal` to `public`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation")]` is a right thought, but this will not work, as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` is the dynamically generated assembly at runtime.

In the previous version you did not faced issue because the Razor view engine generated code was part of the same assembly as the project's code.

you could try creating a separate strong-named assembly (Project) that has access to your `internal` class using `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourIntermediateAssembly")]`.In this intermediate assembly, create public classes or wrappers to expose the necessary functionality.Reference this intermediate assembly in your web project and use these public classes in Razor views.

Just a reminder by using the InternalsVisibleTo you are exposing the internal class, make sure that it doesn't pose a security risk for your application.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of that design change. A pity it results in this side effect for access modifiers.